# How to differentiate development environment of production environment on cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, environment-variables, .env

I would like to know if there is a way to find out if I'm in development or production. I have a **BASE_URL** that it should have localhost if I'm running the emulator but when I'm deploy to prod it should be my domain for example

`const BASE_URL = isProd ? 'https://mydomain' : 'http://localhost:3000'`

Comment: What's wrong with the env vars you mentioned?  That would be the way to configure your code to do what you want on a particular deployment where those vars are set properly.  Cloud Functions has no sense of "environment" - you have to give that meaning to the vars you use. Is there something you tried that didn't work the way you expected?

Comment: No, forget about the env variables. I have to send a url back to the client, but I would like to verify if i'm on prod or dev. For example res.send({{url:isProd? 'https://mydomain':'http://localhost')

Comment: I would do this with environment variables. That's how you tell the code where it's running and how to behave in any situation.  What's wrong with that?

Comment: Can you show me how to do it? I have no clue

Comment: I updated the question with what i am trying to do

Comment: I suggest starting with the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env) to understand how it functions, then adapt that to your situation.  Make a variable for isProd and give it a value it according to the deployment.  If you've tried something specific and it doesn't work the way you expect, please explain that and show your code.